# dataproc - spark configuration

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc

If I give my spark configuration this way:

```
    .config("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "true")
    .config("spark.executor.memory", "12gb")
    .config("spark.executor.cores", "4")
    .config("spark.executor.instances", "3")
    .config("spark.driver.memory", "12g")
    .config("spark.driver.cores", 4)
    .config("spark.driver.maxResultSize", 0)
```

Will the dataproc job run with `spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled` or with the given set of memory resource configurations? Which will be given priority?

Comment: Does this [document](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html) help?